# How $\text{vol} \ (I) - \text{vol} \ (J) < \epsilon$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In the proof of Proposition 18.7 in *Advanced Calculus* by Fitzpatrick states following note without a proof (which I re-write in more details):

Let $I$ be a generalized rectangle in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there is a generalized rectangle $J$ that is contained in the interior of $I$ and has the property that $\text{vol} \ (I) - \text{vol} \ (J) < \epsilon $.

I go by intuition and induction, but I am satisfied as it doesn't look a rigorous mathematical proof:

For one dimensional space let the inside interval's end points be $\epsilon /3$ distance from the original interval so $\text{vol} \ (I) - \text{vol} \ (J) = 2 \epsilon /3 < \epsilon$.

For two dimensional space let the inside rectangle's edges be $\delta$ distance from the original rectangle such that such that $4 \delta \min {\{b_i-a_i}\} < 2 \delta (b_1-a_1) + 2 \delta (b_2-a_2) < \epsilon$.

By induction I guess and I can't prove that number of ending boundaries of generalized rectangle in $n$ dimensional space must be $2n$ (interval has two ending points, rectangle has 4 ending edges and so on).

So if we set the distance between 'edges' of the insider and outsider generalized rectangles be $\delta$ such that $2n \delta \min {\{D_j}\}$ then $\text{vol} \ (I) - \text{vol} \ (J) < \epsilon$ holds; in which $\min {\{D_j}\}$ is the product of all $b_i - a_i$'s except $b_j -a_j$ is missing.

How is a rigorous proof for the mentioned claim in the book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a rectangle $I = [a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,b_2] \times \ldots \times [a_n,b_n]$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and would like to produce a rectangle $J \subset I$ such that $\text{vol}(I) - \text{vol}(J) < \epsilon$ where $\epsilon < \text{vol}(I)$.

Take $J = [a'_1,b'_1] \times [a'_2,b'_2] \times \ldots \times [a'_n,b'_n]$ where $[a'_k,b'_k] \subset [a_k,b_k]$ and $b'_k - a'_k = \alpha(b_k-a_k)$ with

$$\alpha = \left(1 - \frac{\epsilon'}{\text{vol}(I)}\right)^{1/n} \quad(\epsilon' < \epsilon)$$

We then have

$$\text{vol}(I) - \text{vol}(J) = \prod_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k) - \prod_{k=1}^n\alpha (b_k-a_k)= \text{vol}(I)(1 - \alpha^n) = \epsilon' < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 1):

If you know that multiplication is a continuous function, then it follows that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that, if you change each of the sides of your given generalized rectangle by less than $\delta$, you change the volume by $<\varepsilon$. So shrink each side by $\delta/2$.